# Java Heap Space when Sign a Pdf with IText 7

Tags: pdf, itext, digital-signature, itext7

I crate this method to sign a pdf file:

```
public File sign7(File pdfOriginal,
                          String diretorioSalvar,
                          String nomeArquivo,
                          String motivo, String local,
                          LocalDateTime data,
                          String textoAssinatura,
                          boolean visible,
                          PDFService.DisposicaoPagina dispPagina,
                          File arquivoOriginal
                          ) throws IOException, DocumentException, GeneralSecurityException {

            log.debug("comecou assinar");
            File diretorioSaida = new File(diretorioSalvar);
            diretorioSaida.mkdirs();
            File pdfAssinado = new File(diretorioSalvar+File.separator+nomeArquivo);
            String keystore_password = KEYSTORE_PASSWORD;
            String key_password = KEYSTORE_PASSWORD;
            keystore.load(KEYSTORE.getInputStream(), keystore_password.toCharArray());

            PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey) keystore.getKey(alias, key_password.toCharArray());
            Certificate[] chain = keystore.getCertificateChain(alias);

            log.debug("keystore provider   : {}", keystore.getProvider().getName());
            log.debug("Assinando com alias :{}", alias);
            log.debug("chain size: " + chain.length);

            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new RandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream(pdfOriginal));
            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(pdfAssinado);
            PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(reader,writer);
            FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(pdfAssinado);

            PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(doc.getReader(),os,true);
            signer.setCertificationLevel(PdfSigner.NOT_CERTIFIED);


            //TEXTO DO CARIMBO
            String texto;
            ImageData imgCarimbo;


            PdfPage moldPage = doc.getLastPage();
            PageSize pSize = new PageSize(moldPage.getPageSize());
            PdfCanvas cPage = new PdfCanvas(moldPage);


            PdfFont font = null;
            try {
                font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FONT.getFile().getPath(), PdfEncodings.WINANSI, true);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            cPage.setFillColor(Color.BLACK);

            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(
                    (float) (pSize.getWidth()*0.653),  //0.725  Y
                    (float) (pSize.getHeight()*0.9),  //0.90    X
                    (float) (pSize.getWidth()*0.32),   //0.25   Largura
                    (float) (pSize.getHeight()*0.068)); //0.07   Altura



            cPage.fillStroke();


            PdfFormXObject xObject = new PdfFormXObject(rect);

            Image rectImg = new Image(xObject);

            ImageData imgLogoCarimboOval = ImageDataFactory.create(LOGO_CARIMBO_DIGITAL.getFile().getPath());
            ImageData imgLogoCarimboBg = ImageDataFactory.create(LOGO_CARIMBO_BG.getFile().getPath());


            int paginaAparencia = (dispPagina == PDFService.DisposicaoPagina.ULTIMA_PAGINA?doc.getNumberOfPages():1);

            String arqOriginalHash = "";
            if (arquivoOriginal != null) {
                arqOriginalHash = pdfService.gerarHash(arquivoOriginal);
            }

            PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer
                    .getSignatureAppearance()
                    .setReason(motivo + " - Hash: " + arqOriginalHash)
                    .setLocation(local)
                    .setReuseAppearance(false)
                    .setImage(imgLogoCarimboBg)
                    .setSignatureGraphic(imgLogoCarimboOval)
                    .setImageScale(100)
                    .setRenderingMode(RenderingMode.GRAPHIC_AND_DESCRIPTION)
                    .setPageRect(rect)
                    .setLayer2Font(font)
                    .setLayer2FontSize(6)
                    .setLayer2Text(textoAssinatura)
                    .setPageNumber(paginaAparencia);



            signer.setFieldName(signer.getNewSigFieldName());
            // Creating the signature
            IExternalSignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(key, DigestAlgorithms.SHA1, "BC");
            IExternalDigest digest = new ProviderDigest("BC");


            Collection<ICrlClient> crlList=null; IOcspClient ocspClient = null; ITSAClient tsaClient=null;

            writer.close();
            signer.signDetached(digest, pks, chain, crlList, ocspClient, tsaClient, 0, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS);
            reader.close();

            os.close();
            log.debug("acabou assinar");
            return pdfAssinado;
    }
```

(This method create an stamp in my last page and sign the pdf) But when I try to sign a 500MB file I got a java Heap Space in line:

```
signer.signDetached(digest, pks, chain, crlList, ocspClient, tsaClient, 0, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

If I try to sign smaller files works (I only tried one by one, don't know if I try more than one at same time I will get the same error)

I already try to change the memory from my app withou success.

Comment: *"I already try to change the memory from my app withou success."* - How much memory did you assign to that process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `PdfReader` instantiation

In your `PdfReader` instantiation you mix up PDF libraries with the result of an extra memory requirement for a copy of the original file in memory plus a bit. For a `File pdfOriginal` you do:

```java
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new RandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream(pdfOriginal));
```

`RandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream` is not an iText class! But there is a PDFBox class of this name which I assume you use here. This PDFBox class is an `InputStream` which also implements PDFBox' `RandomAccessRead` interface working on a local file system file in a generalized random access manner.

As iText does have its own mechanisms to implement file random access and in particular does not use the PDFBox interfaces for this, it only recognizes and uses a `RandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream` instance as an `InputStream`. Thus, iText reads all the data from that Stream into a `byte[]` for proper random access support.

If instead you allow iText to see that the source is a local file system file, it can use its own random file access and does not create an in-memory copy of the file. Simply use

```java
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfOriginal);
```

For your *500MB file* this will reduce memory usage by 500 MB plus a bit already.

#### Extra `PdfWriter` and `PdfDocument` instances

Furthermore, you do

```java
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(pdfAssinado);
PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(reader,writer);
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(pdfAssinado);

PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(doc.getReader(),os,true);
```

I.e. you create a `PdfWriter` and a `PdfDocument` instance yourself which only use up additional memory and then create a `PdfSigner` with its own internal `PdfWriter` and `PdfDocument` instances.

Thus, don't create your own `PdfWriter` and `PdfDocument` instances. You access your own `PdfDocument` instance later to determine a page size; you should instead use that of the `PdfSigner`

```java
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(pdfAssinado);
PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader,os,true);
PdfDocument doc = signer.getDocument();
```

and remove the later `writer.close()` instruction.

This reduces memory usage by whatever those extra objects need.

#### Temporary file copy in memory

You instantiate the `PdfSigner` like this:

```java
PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader,os,true);
```

As documented in the JavaDocs, this constructor keeps the intermediary file copy (required during signature creation) in a `ByteArrayOutputStream` instance, i.e. in memory:

```java
/**
 * Creates a PdfSigner instance. Uses a {@link java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream} instead of a temporary file.
 *
 * @param reader       PdfReader that reads the PDF file
 * @param outputStream OutputStream to write the signed PDF file
 * @param append       boolean to indicate whether the signing should happen in append mode or not
 * @throws IOException
 * @deprecated         will be removed in next major release.
 *                     Use {@link #PdfSigner(PdfReader, OutputStream, StampingProperties)} instead.
 */
@Deprecated
public PdfSigner(PdfReader reader, OutputStream outputStream, boolean append) throws IOException
```

Instead provide a temporary file in the file system for this:

```java
String temporaryFile = pdfAssinado.getAbsolutePath() + ".tmp";
PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, os, temporaryFile, true);
```

For your *500MB file* this will again reduce memory usage by 500 MB plus a bit.

---

The changes above will reduce your memory footprint by more than 1 GB when signing your 500 MB file. I don't know if that suffices but that should at least lessen the memory requirement considerably.

Comment: Thank you! for all the solutions and references provided.The temporary file did the trick to alleviate the JVM from storing a huge byte[] and later get garbage collected delegating the hard work to the file system (which in our case makes sense)

Comment: Great! I would propose using all the optimizations mentioned above, though, for the lowest memory footprint.